# Windows 10 - create shortcuts via Drag 'n Drop from Task bar

Tags: windows-10

In windows 7 I was used to create shortcuts with drag 'n dropping items to the taskbar and vice versa. That was intuitive and simple.

In windows 10, I'm not able to
- Drag 'n Drop items from the desktop to the task bar (you have to right-click the icon and pin it to start)
- Drag 'n Drop items from task bar to desktop

In addition, it's not possible to press windows-key, enter name of app, and create a shortcut to the desktop (you have to "pin it to start", then you can create the shorcut via drag 'n drop)

So it seems Microsoft removed every efficient (and of course familiar) way to create shortcuts :D
Sure, I can "learn" the new cumbersome way creating shortcuts, but I want to know of there's a way to get the old behaviour back. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, it's done this way intentionally and there is no workaround.

Comment: Hey Victor, do you know which intensions led tot this decision?

Answer (score 0):

Some people say that disabling UAC solves the drag and drop problem, but I haven't tried it personally, because using Windows without UAC is obviously not a good idea in the long run, it would create a lot of security issues. Still, if drag and drop is important for you, you might give it a try.

Others mention that installing latest updates helps with this problem. It's not hard to do, so give it a shot.

Drag and drop feature is missing in multiple parts of Windows 10 such as moving files between folders, arranging icons on the desktop, sticking applications to the taskbar, etc. It seems to be a deliberate decision, but why Microsoft would do that is a mystery.

Here's a thread on the Microsoft site with more info: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-fix-drag-and-drop-in-windows-10/0ea16377-dfcf-4a28-9e38-c35f4113202b?page=1